# Reading from a stream but reserving N bytes at the end of stream

Tags: c++, c++11, io, stream

What I'd like to do is read data from a stream (like ifstream::read), but reserve N = 4 bytes from being returned. The last 4 bytes of the stream are not part of the data itself, but are metadata.

In the general case, the stream is not an ifstream so I won't be able to seek, putback, or determine the size of the stream ahead of time. Here I'm just using it as an example.

My approach is to keep a reserve buffer of 4 bytes to ensure I never accidentally  return the last four bytes of the stream. However, the logic turned out to be pretty hard to manage... I'm hoping there's a cleaner way to accomplish what I want.

I'd like to ask for a code review in terms readability (is there a better approach?) and/or performance (is there anything I'm doing that is suboptimal?)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

#define RESERVE_SIZE 4
static std::array<char, RESERVE_SIZE> reserve = {0,0,0,0}; // buffer for holding bytes at end of stream
static bool first_read = true; // true if first read and reserve buffer is empty

// helper function to print output
void data_printer(std::string msg, char * bd, size_t bytes_read) {
  std::cout << msg << bytes_read << ": ";
  for(size_t i=0; i < bytes_read; i++) std::cout << (int)bd[i] << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

// helper function to read and return # of bytes read
size_t read_count(std::ifstream & myFile, char * dst, size_t length) {
  myFile.read(dst, length);
  return myFile.gcount();
}

// dst -- output buffer, has at least "length" bytes
// exact -- if true, expect "length" bytes read from myFile and copied to dst; throw error if less than that
// return value is the number of bytes read from my File and copied to dst
size_t read_reserve(std::ifstream & myFile, char * dst, size_t length, bool exact=false) {
  if(first_read) {
    myFile.read(reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
    first_read = false;
  }
  if(exact) {
    if(length >= RESERVE_SIZE) {
      std::memcpy(dst, reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
      myFile.read(dst + RESERVE_SIZE, length - RESERVE_SIZE);
      myFile.read(reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
      if(myFile.gcount() != RESERVE_SIZE) throw std::runtime_error("not enough data in file :(");
      return length;
    } else { // RESERVE_SIZE > length
      std::memcpy(dst, reserve.data(), length);
      // since some of the reserve buffer was consumed, shift the unconsumed bytes to beginning of array
      // then read from file to fill up reserve buffer
      std::memmove(reserve.data(), reserve.data() + length, RESERVE_SIZE - length);
      myFile.read(reserve.data() +  RESERVE_SIZE - length, length);
      if(myFile.gcount() != length) throw std::runtime_error("not enough data in file :(");
      return length;
    }
  } else { // !exact -- we can't assume that "length" bytes are left in myFile; there could even be zero bytes left
    if(length >= RESERVE_SIZE) {
      // use "dst" as a temporary buffer, since it's already allocated
      // it is not a good idea to allocate a temp buffer of size length, as length can be large
      std::memcpy(dst, reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
      size_t n_read = read_count(myFile, dst + RESERVE_SIZE, length - RESERVE_SIZE);
      size_t n_bufferable = n_read + RESERVE_SIZE;
      if(n_bufferable < length) {
        std::memcpy(reserve.data(), dst + n_bufferable - RESERVE_SIZE, RESERVE_SIZE);
        return n_bufferable - RESERVE_SIZE;
      } else {
        std::array<char, RESERVE_SIZE> temp_buffer = {0,0,0,0};
        size_t temp_size = read_count(myFile, temp_buffer.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
        std::memcpy(reserve.data(), dst + n_bufferable - (RESERVE_SIZE - temp_size), RESERVE_SIZE - temp_size);
        std::memcpy(reserve.data() + RESERVE_SIZE - temp_size, temp_buffer.data(), temp_size);
        return n_bufferable - (RESERVE_SIZE - temp_size);
      }
    } else { // length < RESERVE_SIZE
      std::vector<char> temp_buffer(length, '\0');
      size_t return_value = read_count(myFile, temp_buffer.data(), length);
      // n_bufferable is at most RESERVE_SIZE*2 - 1 = 7
      std::memcpy(dst, reserve.data(), return_value);
      std::memmove(reserve.data(), reserve.data() + return_value, RESERVE_SIZE - return_value);
      std::memcpy(reserve.data() + (RESERVE_SIZE - return_value), temp_buffer.data(), return_value);
      return return_value;
    }
  }
}

// example function usage
int main() {
  std::ofstream outfile("/tmp/temp.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
  std::array<char, 30> mydata = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29};
  outfile.write(mydata.data(), 30);
  outfile.close();

  std::cout << "test1" << std::endl;
  std::ifstream infile("/tmp/temp.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  std::vector<char> buffer(100, '\0');
  size_t bytes_read;
  char * bd = buffer.data();
  bytes_read = read_reserve(infile, bd, 3, true); data_printer("bytes read: ", bd, bytes_read); data_printer("reserve: ", reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
  bytes_read = read_reserve(infile, bd, 3, false); data_printer("bytes read: ", bd, bytes_read); data_printer("reserve: ", reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
  bytes_read = read_reserve(infile, bd, 5, true); data_printer("bytes read: ", bd, bytes_read); data_printer("reserve: ", reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
  bytes_read = read_reserve(infile, bd, 5, false); data_printer("bytes read: ", bd, bytes_read); data_printer("reserve: ", reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
  bytes_read = read_reserve(infile, bd, 100, false); data_printer("bytes read: ", bd, bytes_read); data_printer("reserve: ", reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
  infile.close();

  std::cout << "test2" << std::endl;
  first_read = true;
  std::ifstream infile2("/tmp/temp.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  bytes_read = read_reserve(infile2, bd, 28, false); data_printer("bytes read: ", bd, bytes_read); data_printer("reserve: ", reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
  bytes_read = read_reserve(infile2, bd, 3, false); data_printer("bytes read: ", bd, bytes_read); data_printer("reserve: ", reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
  infile2.close();
}

// g++ -std=c++11 -O3 read_reserve.cpp -o test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the code looks nice.  It is structured and well-formatted.

It is probably a bad idea to have more than 80 characters in each line, because this may happen:

[image: line wrapping]

Also, put the body of a control statement on a separate line.  For example, instead of

```
for(size_t i=0; i < bytes_read; i++) std::cout << (int)bd[i] << " ";
```

do

```
for (size_t i=0; i < bytes_read; i++)
  std::cout << (int)bd[i] << " ";
```

(more on this loop later.)

## General design

It seems that you are using a translation unit as a "module" and use global `static` variables for implementation.  Requiring the user to set `first_read` manually feels wrong.  What you are developing is a class that wraps the functionalities.

Also, your `read_reserve` function is way too complex.  A rule of thumb is that if a function is longer than about 10 lines, it is doing too much.  In your case, the `exact` parameter should be a separate function:

```
class Reader {
public:
    Reader(std::istream& i)
        :is{i}
    {
        init();
    }

    std::streamsize read      (char* dst, std::streamsize length);
    std::streamsize read_exact(char* dst, std::streamsize length);

    // for the test
    void print_reserve(std::ostream& os);

private:
    void init();
    std::streamsize read_count(char* dst, std::streamsize length);

    std::istream& is;

    static constexpr std::size_t reserve_size = 4;
    std::array<char, reserve_size> reserve{};
};

void Reader::init()
{
    read_count(reserve.data(), reserve_size);
}
```

This way, the user does not need to bother with `first_read`.  They simply create a `Reader` object when they want to read something.  The implementation also doesn't have to check for `first_read` each time.

## Code

Now let's go through the code and figure out some possible improvements.

---

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <array>
> #include <vector>
> #include <fstream>
> #include <cstring>
> ```

It is considered good practice to sort the `#include`s in alphabetical order, so that you can easily figure out whether a particular header is included.  Like:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
```

In particular, you forgot `#include <cstddef>` for `std::size_t`.

> ```
> #define RESERVE_SIZE 4
> static std::array<char, RESERVE_SIZE> reserve = {0,0,0,0}; // buffer for holding bytes at end of stream
> static bool first_read = true; // true if first read and reserve buffer is empty
> ```

In C++, don't use `#define` for constants.  Use `constexpr` instead.

```
constexpr std::size_t reserve_size = 4;
```

The initialization of `reserve` can be a simple `{}` instead of `= {0,0,0,0}`.  In my opinion, that's clearer.

---

> ```
> // helper function to print output
> void data_printer(std::string msg, char * bd, size_t bytes_read) {
>   std::cout << msg << bytes_read << ": ";
>   for(size_t i=0; i < bytes_read; i++) std::cout << (int)bd[i] << " ";
>   std::cout << std::endl;
> }
> ```

Don't take `msg` by value.  Take by const reference instead.  Also, I don't see why `bd` is a non-const pointer.  `size_t` should be `std::size_t`.  Prefer `++i` over `i++`.  In C++, [avoid C-style casts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/103512).  [Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907) when flushing is not needed.  Something along the lines of:

```
// helper function to print output
void data_printer(const std::string& msg, const char * bd, std::size_t bytes_read)
{
  std::cout << msg << bytes_read << ": ";
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < bytes_read; ++i)
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(bd[i]) << ' ';
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

I would put a space after the `for` keyword, but that is a matter of taste, I guess.

Also, the STL algorithms can be used here: (needs `#include <algorithm>` and `#include <iterator>`)

```
// helper function to print output
void data_printer(const std::string& msg, const char* bd, std::size_t bytes_read)
{
  std::cout << msg << bytes_read << ": ";
  std::copy_n(bd, bytes_read, std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "});
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

In fact, I feel that `msg` doesn't fit in here well.  And it would be nice if you take a `std::ostream&` parameter instead of always outputting to `std::cout`.  Also, this function may deserve an `inline`.  I may write the function like this:

```
void print_data(std::ostream& os, const char* data, std::size_t cnt)
{
    std::copy_n(bd, bytes_read, std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "});
}
```

and let the user handle the message and/or newline.  It would be even nicer if we write an I/O manipulator so that we can use it like

```
std::cout << "bytes read: " << print_data(bd, bytes_read) << '\n';
```

The implementation is left as an exercise to the reader.  (oops)

---

> ```
> // helper function to read and return # of bytes read
> size_t read_count(std::ifstream & myFile, char * dst, size_t length) {
>   myFile.read(dst, length);
>   return myFile.gcount();
> }
> ```

Nice little function.  Also a good candidate for `inline`.  `myFile` can be any `std::istream`, not just `std::ifstream`.  It may be better to use `std::streamsize` instead of `std::size_t` here:

```
// helper function to read and return # of bytes read
std::streamsize read_count(std::istream& myFile, char* dst, std::streamsize length)
{
  myFile.read(dst, length);
  return myFile.gcount();
}
```

Also, stream operations can be chained, but I'm not sure whether `return myFile.read(dst, length).gcount()` is more readable.

---

Initialization code:

> ```
> myFile.read(reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
> ```

As I wrote above, since you wrote `read_count`, why not use it?

---

Non-exact reading code, part one:

> ```
> if(length >= RESERVE_SIZE) {
>   std::memcpy(dst, reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
>   myFile.read(dst + RESERVE_SIZE, length - RESERVE_SIZE);
>   myFile.read(reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
>   if(myFile.gcount() != RESERVE_SIZE) throw std::runtime_error("not enough data in file :(");
>   return length;
> }
> ```

Here, the logic is actually simpler than it seems to be: emit the cached data, read the remaining characters and emit immediately, and then read and cache specified amount of data.  It would be nice if you place a comment explaining this.  Also, `std::copy` is easier to work with than `std::memcpy`, and it increments the pointer for you.  (`std::copy` automatically calls `std::memcpy` for trivial types, so there is no performance quality.)  And since you have written `read_count`, use it.  I am starting to feel that the if statement deserves its own function:

```
void read_ensure(char* dest, std::streampos size)
{
    if (read_count(dest, size) != size)
        throw std::runtime{"not enough data in file :("};
}
```

then you can use it to make the code more readable:

```
if (length >= reserve_size) {
    dst = std::copy(reserve.begin(), reserve.end(), dst);
    read_count(dst, length - reserve_size);
    read_ensure(reserve.data(), reserve_size);
}
```

The return statement is common to both branches, so don't repeat it.

---

Non-exact reading code, part two:

> ```
> else { // RESERVE_SIZE > length
>   std::memcpy(dst, reserve.data(), length);
>   // since some of the reserve buffer was consumed, shift the unconsumed bytes to beginning of array
>   // then read from file to fill up reserve buffer
>   std::memmove(reserve.data(), reserve.data() + length, RESERVE_SIZE - length);
>   myFile.read(reserve.data() +  RESERVE_SIZE - length, length);
>   if(myFile.gcount() != length) throw std::runtime_error("not enough data in file :(");
>   return length;
> }
> ```

We can use `std::copy` here since we know the direction: (`std::copy` is likely to call `std::memmove` internally)

```
else {
    std::copy(reserve.begin(), reserve.end(), dst);
    std::copy(reserve.begin() + length, reserve.end(), reserve.begin());
    read_ensure(reserve, length);
}
```

---

Exact reading code, part one:

> ```
> if(length >= RESERVE_SIZE) {
>   // use "dst" as a temporary buffer, since it's already allocated
>   // it is not a good idea to allocate a temp buffer of size length, as length can be large
>   std::memcpy(dst, reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
>   size_t n_read = read_count(myFile, dst + RESERVE_SIZE, length - RESERVE_SIZE);
>   size_t n_bufferable = n_read + RESERVE_SIZE;
>   if(n_bufferable < length) {
>     std::memcpy(reserve.data(), dst + n_bufferable - RESERVE_SIZE, RESERVE_SIZE);
>     return n_bufferable - RESERVE_SIZE;
>   } else {
>     std::array<char, RESERVE_SIZE> temp_buffer = {0,0,0,0};
>     size_t temp_size = read_count(myFile, temp_buffer.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
>     std::memcpy(reserve.data(), dst + n_bufferable - (RESERVE_SIZE - temp_size), RESERVE_SIZE - temp_size);
>     std::memcpy(reserve.data() + RESERVE_SIZE - temp_size, temp_buffer.data(), temp_size);
>     return n_bufferable - (RESERVE_SIZE - temp_size);
>   }
> }
> ```

You are actually leaking the reserved bytes.  You rely on the user to not read them, but are users always careful?  It may be beneficial to `std::fill` the remaining bytes to zero, but that depends on your case.

---

Exact reading code, part two:

> ```
> else { // length < RESERVE_SIZE
>   std::vector<char> temp_buffer(length, '\0');
>   size_t return_value = read_count(myFile, temp_buffer.data(), length);
>   // n_bufferable is at most RESERVE_SIZE*2 - 1 = 7
>   std::memcpy(dst, reserve.data(), return_value);
>   std::memmove(reserve.data(), reserve.data() + return_value, RESERVE_SIZE - return_value);
>   std::memcpy(reserve.data() + (RESERVE_SIZE - return_value), temp_buffer.data(), return_value);
>   return return_value;
> }
> ```

Well, using `std::vector` seems a little bit strange here.  `reserve_size` is a small number, and since you are using it in other places, so why not use `std::array`?

---

> ```
> // example function usage
> int main() {
>   std::ofstream outfile("/tmp/temp.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
>   std::array<char, 30> mydata = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29};
>   outfile.write(mydata.data(), 30);
>   outfile.close();
>
>   std::cout << "test1" << std::endl;
>   std::ifstream infile("/tmp/temp.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
>   std::vector<char> buffer(100, '\0');
>   size_t bytes_read;
>   char * bd = buffer.data();
>   bytes_read = read_reserve(infile, bd, 3, true); data_printer("bytes read: ", bd, bytes_read); data_printer("reserve: ", reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
>   bytes_read = read_reserve(infile, bd, 3, false); data_printer("bytes read: ", bd, bytes_read); data_printer("reserve: ", reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
>   bytes_read = read_reserve(infile, bd, 5, true); data_printer("bytes read: ", bd, bytes_read); data_printer("reserve: ", reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
>   bytes_read = read_reserve(infile, bd, 5, false); data_printer("bytes read: ", bd, bytes_read); data_printer("reserve: ", reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
>   bytes_read = read_reserve(infile, bd, 100, false); data_printer("bytes read: ", bd, bytes_read); data_printer("reserve: ", reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
>   infile.close();
>
>   std::cout << "test2" << std::endl;
>   first_read = true;
>   std::ifstream infile2("/tmp/temp.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
>   bytes_read = read_reserve(infile2, bd, 28, false); data_printer("bytes read: ", bd, bytes_read); data_printer("reserve: ", reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
>   bytes_read = read_reserve(infile2, bd, 3, false); data_printer("bytes read: ", bd, bytes_read); data_printer("reserve: ", reserve.data(), RESERVE_SIZE);
>   infile2.close();
> }
> ```

`out` is implied for `std::ofstream`, and `in` is implied for `std::ifstream`, so omit them.  Initializing `mydata` like that is no fun; `std::iota` is better.  Also, it may be better to use scopes instead of manually calling `close`.  The reading tests are a lot of duplicate code and may deserve a helper function.  Also, the three parts can probably be extracted into their own functions.  This is just a test, so it doesn't really matter too much, though.

Comment: Thank you!  This was more than I could have hoped for! :)